# Cleanup for a static constructor

Tags: node.js, jestjs

So I'm trying to write some unit tests for my library. But when running jest I get the dreaded:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles`
to troubleshoot this issue.
```

I've tracked this down to a specific class I've written that has a static constructor block. In that block I start a `setInterval`, or a `setTimeout` function. Either way I try it jest acts the same way.

So I know Javascript doesn't have destructors for some unknown reason (GC isn't a valid reason. Lots of languages with GCs have destructors). How to I clean up and stop the `setInterval` when the code is ready to shutdown?

Option 1:

```
class A {
  static #blink = false;
  static #blinker;

  static {
    A.#blinker = setInterval(() => {
      A.#blink = !A.#blink;
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
class B {
  static #blink = false;
  static #blinker = null;

  static {
    B.#doBlink();
  }

  static #doBlink() {
    B.#blink = !B.#blink;
    #blinker = setTimeout(() => B.#doBlink(), 500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous choices:

1. Add a `.shutdown()` or `.close()` method to your object and call that method when you're done with the object and want the timers to stop.
2. call `.unref()` on the timers and then they won't keep nodejs from shutting down naturally - they won't count as an unfinished asynchronous operation when the nodejs event loop is detecting whether anything is still running or not.
3. Using the logic of your code (which you don't show), figure out when the timers are no longer needed and shut down the `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` naturally based on those conditions.

Comment: undef did the trick. No clue that even existed. Thank you.